# Fancybox 3 - prevent moblie view swipe up or click overlay area close

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox-3

I am trying to make a fancybox only can close by close button. I have looked the fancyBox3 documentation but still no idea. The fancybox default setting only can prevent mouse click outside close and mouse touch close. Even the touch setting set to false, swipe up or click overlay area close problem still happen on mobile view.

I have a sample script to show the fancybox.

HTML

```
<div id="fancybox" style="display:none;">
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5519/9432166677_61aa7e7f90_m_d.jpg">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
    src: "#fancybox",
    type: "inline",
    clickSlide : 'false',
    clickOutside : 'false',
    touch: false            
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/guzrdm9c/)

Any idea to prevent mobile swipe up close? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “mobile drag up”? Do you actually mean an upwards swipe motion or something like that?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, you can using mobile to view the jsfiddle link, and try to swipe up overlay area, the fancybox will close even "touch" option set to false.

Comment: `touch` option seems to control whether you can navigate to previous/next items by swiping only, but not affect closing behavior. I guess you could try and catch the event that swiping up causes and cancel it in the `beforeClose` handler fancybox provides. Not sure though whether inside that the information what the event causing it to close is available; if not, you might need to use your own event handler to catch that, and then set a flag or something that you can then check for in beforeClose. Would probably have to re-set that flag based on a timer as well ...

Comment: why community give downvote without checking answer...? my answer is correct.

Comment: @jkythc Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Give `"touch":false` instead of `touch: false`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $.fancybox.open({
    src: "#fancybox",
    type: "inline",
    clickSlide : 'false',
    clickOutside : 'false',
    "touch":false 
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<div id="fancybox" style="display:none;">
  <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5519/9432166677_61aa7e7f90_m_d.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: maybe my question not clear, I mean swipe up the overlay black area and it is still close the popup..

Comment: In your fiddle popup close when i swipe up and  in my fiddle without click on close button popup do not closed and i think you want like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can disable vertical dragging:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  touch: {
    vertical: false
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYEQmM

Comment: It is a long story, but here it is how to make it work - https://jsfiddle.net/0Lg41w6s/

Comment: btw, I have updated the first demo, this works in v3.2.

Comment: @Janis would you be able to add any more information on how you resolved it?  I've the same issue where content displayed with Fancybox is closing when being viewed on an Android device.  I can't set touch vertical to false as the content needs to scroll - but when I do scroll, it closes!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, you need add options for mobile devices

```js
    $.fancybox.open({
        src: '#order-popup-desktop',
        type: 'inline',
        mobile: {
            clickSlide: false,
            touch: false
        },
    });
```

This code 100% work for fancy v.3.5.7