# How to disable only drag up to close the fancybox lightbox?

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox, lightbox

I wrote a topic in Fancybox issues, but I posted here to see if anyone had any other options while waiting for them to reply.

Simple I just want to drag down to close the lightbox, like as application mobile.

Because in my web design, the popup is displayed at the bottom of the window, so if we drag up, there is a blank space and it's bad user experience I think...

In my case, just drag down is a good way to make a better UX

[image]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091462/fancybox-3-prevent-moblie-view-swipe-up-or-click-overlay-area-close

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. I still want to drag down to close the lightbox.

Comment: Sorry, there is currently no option for that.